# Cannot Convert IConfigurationSection to Action<T> When Using services.Configure in .NET Core

Tags: amazon-s3, .net-core

I'm having an issue with configuring my AWS settings in an ASP.NET Core application. I've structured my appsettings.json to include AWS configurations, and I'm attempting to bind these settings to my AWSConfiguration POCO using services.Configure in my Startup.cs. However, I'm receiving a conversion error that I can't seem to resolve.

Here's the relevant section from my appsettings.json:

```
"AWSConfiguration": {
    "AWSKey": "",
    "AWSSecretKey": "",
    "Region": "",
    "Bucket": {
      "Name": "",
      "Prefix": "",
      "Url": ""
    }
}
```

And here's my AWSConfiguration class:

```
public class AWSConfiguration
{
    public string AWSKey { get; set; }
    public string AWSSecretKey { get; set; } 
    public string Region { get; set; } 
    public BucketConfiguration Bucket { get; set; } 
}

public class BucketConfiguration
{
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public string Prefix { get; set; } 
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

In my servis registration, I'm using the following line to bind the configuration:

```
public static class InfrastructureServiceRegistration
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructureServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {

        services.Configure<AWSConfiguration>(configuration.GetSection("AWSConfiguration"));

        services.AddSingleton<IAmazonS3>(sp =>
        {
            var awsConfig = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AWSConfiguration>>().Value;
            var region = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(awsConfig.Region);
            return new AmazonS3Client(awsConfig.AWSKey, awsConfig.AWSSecretKey, region);
        });

        services.AddSingleton<IFileStorageService, AWSFileStorageService>();

        return services;
    }

}
```

When I build the application, I receive the following error:

```
Error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationSection' to 'System.Action<Infrastructure.Aws.Configurations.AWSConfiguration>'
```

I'm not sure why this conversion issue is happening. I've checked that my AWSConfiguration class has a parameterless constructor and matches the structure of the appsettings.json section.

Could anyone point out what I might be missing or doing incorrectly?